# What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> They had heard so very little of this; yet it was enough to build up wretched dolorous dreams upon, there in the shade of the night. [(Thomas Hardy, *Tess of the d'Urbervilles*, 1891)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=y1tfxa3aOpMC&pg=PA375&dq=%22wretched%20dolorous%20dreams%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22wretched%20dolorous%20dreams%22&f=false)

Comment: It means what it says. What don't you understand?

Comment: Please explain what you find difficult with the sentence. If it's the referent to *"it"* you're having trouble with, then the meaning is *"They had heard so very little of this; yet what they had heard was enough to build up wretched dolorous dreams upon, there in the shade of the night."* If it's something else you don't understand, this comment does you absolutely no good.

Comment: The three parts can be analyzed (with difficulty) individually.  "It was enough to build up wretched dolorous dreams upon" is the main sentence, the others just set the scene,

Comment: (I'll admit I had to read it three times just to get it to parse.)

Comment: Not much news about this new development had reached them – but enough to give them faint hope, even in the terrible situation they were in.

Comment: @PeterShor, What is "wretched dolorous dreams upon, there in the shade of the night."

Comment: @Edwin: I'm confused by your comment: *wretched dolorous dreams* doesn't convey faint hope to me, but something closer to impending doom.

Comment: @shibly: Please edit the question, and don't just expand on your question in the comments. (Otherwise the question will be closed. This may not make sense to you, but I think the theory is that not everybody reads all the comments.)

Comment: @Peter You're probably right. But I don't like the use of the metaphor 'build up' for 'visions of impending doom'; I was taking it as the merest of improvements in their mental state/s.

Comment: @Peter 'I've worked my way up from nothing to a state of extreme wretchedness and dolorousness'.

Answer (score 3):

The girls don't have much information to go on. (That doesn't make it any less worrying)

The rumours they have heard are turning into sad, disturbing horrors.

It is keeping them all awake in the dark restless night.

[ I wish I could pack as much into one sentence as Hardy does.]